# Not getting proper internet speed over WiFi in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: internet, 17.04

I am not getting proper internet speed in my Ubuntu 17.04 over the wireless connection. My mobile device and other laptop are getting proper internet speed. Please mention what more information is needed so that you can understand the problem.

I am getting following output from the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [17aa:f101]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

`nmcli d show` command is giving following output:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         60:D8:19:36:AC:3A
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Gateway
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.105/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4641:2af2:d5d6:b998/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         br-23ac3a4d281d
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:1E:36:5E:73
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.18.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::42:1eff:fe36:5e73/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:9B:10:4A:8A
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         DC:0E:A1:64:A4:59
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         veth6dfaaec
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         CE:28:53:0F:37:BC
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

`iwconfig` command is giving following output:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

br-23ac3a4d281d  no wireless extensions.

veth6dfaaec  no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Gateway"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 98:DE:D0:98:26:08   
          Bit Rate=121.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:220  Invalid misc:50251   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`nmcli d wifi` is giving following output:

```
*  SSID             MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
   JioFi2_A3C7E6    Infra  10    54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
*  Gateway          Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  77      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
```

When I am using JioFi2_A3C7E6 connection I am getting proper internet speed and that is same for both my mobile device and Ubuntu laptop.

But when I am using Gateway connection then I am not getting good speed on my ubuntu laptop but in my mobile device internet speed is good.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Add result for nmcli d show and iwconfig terminal commands, please.

Comment: Interestingly Link Quality = 70/70 and bad connection, nmcli d wifi gives another parameter of quality, can you post it, please?

Comment: Support Linux for this rt3090 chipset is very poor, It's use rt2800pci driver, however, is not working with this chipset very well, sometimes it is not possible to use higher rate than 2Mb/s. I'm member of Ubuntu Forum Brazil and recently we faced this question at https://ubuntuforum-br.org/index.php/topic,122223.msg671780.html#msg671780 There Forum language is portuguese but commands is same, so it's possible understand. There are three things you can do to improve the connection: channel, disable IPv6 (if possible) and Country Code. This last is the most important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve quality connection:

1. Check router channel
2. Disable IPv6 (if possible)

   Firefox browser:

   about:config
   boolean key network.dns.disableIPv6 'false' to 'true'
   globally

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   add:

   ```
   ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
   ```

   to activate:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -p
   ```

   check:

   ```
   ip -o -6 addr show wlan0 | sed -e 's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/'
   ```

   OK if result is nothing
3. Country Code (most important)

   check yours:

   ```
   sudo iw reg get
   ```

   find and set it temporarily to yours country:

   e.g.:

   ```
   sudo iw reg set BR
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo iw reg set IN
   ```

   Set it permanently:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/crda
   ```

   e.g.:

   ```
   REGDOMAIN=BR
   ```

   or

   ```
   REGDOMAIN=IN
   ```